# Share Functions among Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins pipeline, I created 4 Jobs, each job has some functions and Their is a redundant function existing in all those Jobs.

How to make that redundant function in a shared place and all those jobs can call this function ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Jenkins shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)

As the name suggest, you create a library - a pipeline shared among jenkins jobs - in a SCM (git svn ...) and in your project you create a simple Jenkinsfile calling the library.

So,  every build will checkout your project, read the Jenkinsfile and then checkout the library with the pipeline.

Comment: Is their another way does not include SCM ?, Like a shared file in Jenkins itself ?

Comment: Not easily, technically you could use the [filesystem scm plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem_scm) (its quite outdaten but should still work) and the [config-file-provider plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/config-file-provider), and a job that writes the config file to the filesystem scm location that is configured as your global script library.

Comment: Thanks a million for your support, could you please check my anther below and share with me your comments

Answer (score 0):

I did it by:

1. Created Folder in Jenkins working home
2. In that folder => I Created file.groovy contains the functions i need
3. At the end of that file should contain

   return this
4. in JenkinsFile add

   node{shared_functionality = load "FilePath.groovy"}
5. This number four will include functions in .groovy file in your jenkinsFile
6. So you can add node statement in your JenkinsFiles to include Functions you need